# How to draw a histogram with different colors and a legend with those colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

data       = np.array(np.random.rand(1000))
y,binEdges = np.histogram(data,bins=10)
bincenters = 0.5*(binEdges[1:]+binEdges[:-1])
menStd     = np.sqrt(y)
width      = 0.05
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
plt.show()
```

It looks like this:

[image]

However I am looking a plot like this:

[image]

so I have to make one of the boxes white, lets say the 4th one, and then color the other bars based on that bar as the "center".
And I also need to add a legend like the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) and a [norm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) to assign custom colors to the bars. Here is an example giving the mean the central color.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm

data = np.array(np.random.rand(1000))
y, binEdges = np.histogram(data, bins=10)
bincenters = 0.5 * (binEdges[1:] + binEdges[:-1])
menStd = np.sqrt(y)
width = 0.05
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=y.mean(), vmin=y.min(), vmax=y.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color=cmap(norm(y)), yerr=menStd)
plt.xticks(binEdges.round(1))
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap))
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with bars colored relative to mean]

To set the fourth bar completely white, you could use the value of that fourth bar as central color. And use a colormap that uses completely white in the center:

```
norm = TwoSlopeNorm(vcenter=y[3], vmin=y.min(), vmax=y.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap('seismic')
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color=cmap(norm(y)), edgecolor='black', yerr=menStd)
```

[image: making the fourth bar white]

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, would it be posssible to make one of the bars my baseline and make it white? Lets say the 4th bar is my baseline and I want to render it white, everything abovve that bar will be colored light red to dark red, and everything below that bar willl be colored light blue to dark blue.

Comment: In the creation of the `TwoSlopeNorm` you can set `vcenter=y[3]` to have the fourth complete white.  The `coolwarm` colormap is grey in the center, but you could e.g. use the `seismic` colormap to have white in the center.

Answer (score 2):

You can add colors by just editing the following in your code:

```
list_of_colors = ['black', 'red', 'green']
plt.bar(bincenters, y, width=width, color=list_of_colors, yerr=menStd)
```

If you add 3 items to color list like i did then the first, fourth, seventh.... bar will be same color. if you want 10 different color for 10 bar your list should have that 10 color.

For the legend i dont know a way.
Chechk this  site for colored bars : https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/3-control-color-of-barplots